# Compilation error: call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url), How can i solve this issue?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I run this code and get the massage:

Compilation error: call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)

what can I do?

```
//----------------------------------------Include the NodeMCU ESP8266 Library
//----------------------------------------see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jMr94B8iN0 to add NodeMCU ESP8266 library and board
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>

//----------------------------------------

#define ON_Board_LED 2  //--> Defining an On Board LED (GPIO2 = D4), used for indicators when the process of connecting to a wifi router

#define LED_D8 15 //--> Defines an LED Pin. D8 = GPIO15



//---------------------------------------SSID and Password of your WiFi router.
const char* ssid = "*wifi name*"; //--> Your wifi name or SSID.
const char* password = "*Wfif password*"; //--> Your wifi password.
//----------------------------------------

//----------------------------------------Web Server address / IPv4
// If using IPv4, press Windows key + R then type cmd, then type ipconfig (If using Windows OS).
const char *host = "https://localhost/";
//----------------------------------------

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //--> Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");
    
  pinMode(ON_Board_LED,OUTPUT); //--> On Board LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led On Board

  pinMode(LED_D8,OUTPUT); //--> LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(LED_D8, LOW); //--> Turn off Led

  //----------------------------------------Wait for connection
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    //----------------------------------------
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If successfully connected to the wifi router, the IP Address that will be visited is displayed in the serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  //----------------------------------------
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  HTTPClient http; //--> Declare object of class HTTPClient
  WiFiClient WiFiClient;

  //----------------------------------------Getting Data from MySQL Database
  String GetAddress, LinkGet, getData;
  int id = 0; //--> ID in Database
  GetAddress = "rafael/GetData.php"; 
  LinkGet = host + GetAddress; //--> Make a Specify request destination
  getData = "ID=" + String(id);
  Serial.println("----------------Connect to Server-----------------");
  Serial.println("Get LED Status from Server or Database");
  Serial.print("Request Link : ");
  Serial.println(LinkGet);
  http.begin("LinkGet");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    //Specify content-type header
  int httpCodeGet = http.POST(getData); //--> Send the request
  String payloadGet = http.getString(); //--> Get the response payload from server
  Serial.print("Response Code : "); //--> If Response Code = 200 means Successful connection, if -1 means connection failed. For more information see here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
  Serial.println(httpCodeGet); //--> Print HTTP return code
  Serial.print("Returned data from Server : ");
  Serial.println(payloadGet); //--> Print request response payload

  if (payloadGet == "1") {
    digitalWrite(LED_D8, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led
  }
  if (payloadGet == "0") {
    digitalWrite(LED_D8, LOW); //--> Turn off Led
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  
  Serial.println("----------------Closing Connection----------------");
  http.end(); //--> Close connection
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Please wait 5 seconds for the next connection.");
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000); //--> GET Data at every 5 seconds
}
```

I want my esp8266 to connect to my database(MySql) and get a value to turn on/off a led light.

The esp im using is the NodeMCU epp8266.

Comment: The solution is in the message you posted, have you tried doing what it told you to do?

Comment: see the examples of the ESP8266HttpClient library

Comment: @jarl-malte-edwin-lyckoskold is this resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the actual issue that causes the compile error there are several other things wrong with this code. I fixed the most obvious ones. See the explanations for the callouts below the code.

```
// <1>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//#include <WiFiClient.h>
//#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>

#define ON_Board_LED 2
#define LED_D8 15

const char* ssid = "********";
const char* password = "********";

// <2>
// <3>
const char* host = "http://192.168.1.1/";

// <4>
String GetAddress, LinkGet, getData;
int id = 0;

// <5>
HTTPClient http; 
WiFiClient client;

// <6>
void connectWiFi() {
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
  }
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  // <7>
  GetAddress = "rafael/GetData.php";
  LinkGet = host + GetAddress;
  getData = "ID=" + String(id);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  pinMode(ON_Board_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);

  pinMode(LED_D8, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_D8, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  
  // <8>
//  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
//  HTTPClient http; //--> Declare object of class HTTPClient
//  WiFiClient WiFiClient;

  // <9>
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    connectWiFi();  
  }

  Serial.println("----------------Connect to Server-----------------");
  Serial.println("Get LED Status from Server or Database");
  Serial.print("Request Link : ");
  Serial.println(LinkGet);

  // <10>
  http.begin(client, LinkGet);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  int httpCodeGet = http.POST(getData);
  String payloadGet = http.getString();
  
  Serial.print("Response Code : ");
  Serial.println(httpCodeGet);
  Serial.print("Returned data from Server : ");
  Serial.println(payloadGet);

  if (payloadGet == "1") {
    digitalWrite(LED_D8, HIGH);
  }
  if (payloadGet == "0") {
    digitalWrite(LED_D8, LOW);
  }

  Serial.println("----------------Closing Connection----------------");
  http.end();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Please wait 5 seconds for the next connection.");
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

1. Clean up the includes such that only those remain which you actually need.
2. With this sketch your host cannot be (and likely is not) reachable using SSL/TLS encryption (`https` -> `http`).
3. `localhost` is wrong as this would point to the ESP8266 itself (loopback). You need the PC IP address or possibly its hostname here.
4. Declare global variables globally i.e. outside `loop()`.
5. Declare and initialize the `HTTPClient` and `WiFiClient` globally rather than inside the `loop()`. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701884/131929 for more.
6. Put the WiFi-connecting code in a separate function - you'll need it later.
7. Initialize the global variables in `setup()` rather than `loop()`; goes along with <4>.
8. Don't instantiate those over and over again; goes along with <5>.
9. Verify the device is still connected to WiFi every time `loop()` is invoked and re-connect if not.
10. **Compile error**: `http.begin()` takes a `WiFiClient` plus that actual HTTP address. This is what the compile error message tells you.